# When I try to integrate logstash with logback, I get the following error

Tags: logstash

```
10:47:32,020 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - 'File' option has the same value "/Users/yardans/logs/nacos/config.log" as that given for appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE] defined earlier.
10:47:32,020 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting.
10:47:32,020 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#earlier_fa_collision
10:47:32,022 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - 'File' option has the same value "/Users/yardans/logs/nacos/naming.log" as that given for appender [NAMING_LOG_FILE] defined earlier.
10:47:32,022 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting.
10:47:32,022 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#earlier_fa_collision
10:47:32,603 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - 'File' option has the same value "/Users/yardans/logs/nacos/config.log" as that given for appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE] defined earlier.
10:47:32,603 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting.
10:47:32,603 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#earlier_fa_collision
10:47:32,604 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - 'File' option has the same value "/Users/yardans/logs/nacos/naming.log" as that given for appender [NAMING_LOG_FILE] defined earlier.
10:47:32,604 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting.
10:47:32,604 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#earlier_fa_collision
10:47:32,611 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Attempted to append to non started appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE].
10:47:32,611 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Attempted to append to non started appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE].
10:47:32,611 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Attempted to append to non started appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE].
10:47:32,611 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Attempted to append to non started appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE].
10:47:32,612 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Attempted to append to non started appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE].
10:47:32,612 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Attempted to append to non started appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE].
LOGBACK: No context given for net.logstash.logback.LogstashFormatter@7139bd31
10:47:32,756 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - 'File' option has the same value "/Users/yardans/logs/nacos/config.log" as that given for appender [CONFIG_LOG_FILE] defined earlier.
10:47:32,756 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting.
10:47:32,756 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[CONFIG_LOG_FILE] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#earlier_fa_collision
10:47:32,757 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - 'File' option has the same value "/Users/yardans/logs/nacos/naming.log" as that given for appender [NAMING_LOG_FILE] defined earlier.
10:47:32,757 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting.
10:47:32,757 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[NAMING_LOG_FILE] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#earlier_fa_collision
```

Here is my `logback.xml` configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="false">

    <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="loggerFolder" source="logger.folder"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="loggerHost" source="logger.host"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="loggerPort" source="logger.port"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="loggerLevel" source="logger.level"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="loggerConsoleLevel" source="logger.console.level"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="loggerLogstashLevel" source="logger.logstash.level"/>
    <!-- Example for logging into the build folder of your project -->
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${loggerFolder:-/tmp/logback}/${springAppName}/${springAppName}.log"/>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter"/>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex"
                    converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter"/>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx"
                    converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter"/>
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="[%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint}] [%clr(%5p)] [${springAppName}] [%clr(${PID:- }){magenta}] %clr([%15.15t]){faint} [%clr(%class{39}.%M\\(%line\\)){cyan}] %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${loggerConsoleLevel:-DEBUG}</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

        <appender name="logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>${loggerLogstashLevel:-INFO}</level>
            </filter>
            <destination>${loggerHost:-127.0.0.1}:${loggerPort:-5044}</destination>
            <encoder charset="UTF-8" class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
                <customFields>{"appname":"${springAppName}-${logger.env}"}</customFields>
                <providers>
                    <timestamp>
                        <timeZone>Asia/Shanghai</timeZone>
                    </timestamp>
                    <pattern>
                        <pattern>
                            {
                            "logLevel": "%level",
                            "serviceName": "${spring.application.name:-}-${logger.env:-}",
                            "project": "${logger.projectCode:-}",
                            "pid": "${PID:-}",
                            "traceId": "%X{traceId:-}",
                            "thread": "%thread",
                            "class": "%logger{40}",
                            "message": "%message"
                            }
                        </pattern>
                    </pattern>
                </providers>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

    <!-- Appender to log to file -->
    <appender name="flatfile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="error" />
    <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="error" />
    <Logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="warn" />
    <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="warn"/>
    <Logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="warn" />
    <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="error" /> -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" level="warn"/>
    <Logger name="com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ConfigClusterResolver" level="warn"/>
    <logger name="com.gillion.ds" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="${loggerLevel:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
            <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```